# .NET 7 Authentication setup goes in infinite loop

Tags: authentication, infinite-loop, race-condition, .net-7.0, app-startup

This is an intermittent issue that has only happened in one instance so far in an Azure Web Application.  The process crashed with a stack overflow error when trying to register the Authentication service in Startup.cs.  Here is the stack overflow error:

```
========================================================
 Dump Analysis for w3wp__prod-appservice-eus__b6c9__PID__5408__Date__05_04_2023__Time_06_29_42AM__935__ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess_pd0mdwk0007S7.dmp
========================================================
Thread 424
ExitCode 800703E9
ExitCodeString COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW
DefaultHostName prod-appservice-eus.azurewebsites.net
Managed Exception = System.StackOverflowException:
CallStack - Managed Exception
========================================================
CallStack - Crashing Thread
========================================================
     FaultingExceptionFrame
     InlinedCallFrame
     System.Globalization.CompareInfo.FindString(UInt32, System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>, System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>, Int32*)
     System.Globalization.CompareInfo.IsPrefix(System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>, System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>, System.Globalization.CompareOptions)
     System.String.StartsWith(System.String, System.StringComparison)
     AppService.StartupExtensions.Services.AuthenticationAndHttpClientsSetup+<>c.<RegisterAuthenticationServices>b__2_4(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].ResolveTarget(System.String)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].ForbidAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core]](<ForbidAsync>d__16 ByRef)
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core]](<ForbidAsync>d__16 ByRef)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ForbidAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, System.String, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].ForbidAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core]](<ForbidAsync>d__16 ByRef)
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core]](<ForbidAsync>d__16 ByRef)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ForbidAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, System.String, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].ForbidAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core]](<ForbidAsync>d__16 ByRef)
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core]](<ForbidAsync>d__16 ByRef)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ForbidAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, System.String, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext()
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1+<ForbidAsync>d__55[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication]](<ForbidAsync>d__55<System.__Canon> ByRef)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].ForbidAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties)
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService+<ForbidAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
```

As you can see, the Microsoft libraries for Authentication seems to get caught in an endless loop which eventually results in a "recursion too deep" stack overflow.

Here is the code I used to setup authentication:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "DerivedScheme";
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "DerivedScheme";
            })
                .AddPolicyScheme("DerivedScheme", "Authorization Bearer or Token", options =>
                {
                    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
                    {
                        var scheme = context?.Request?.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.StartsWith("Bearer ") == true
                            ? JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                            : WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        return scheme;
                    };
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = configuration["Auth:OIDC:Authority"];
                    options.Audience = configuration["Auth:OIDC:ApiName"];
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.MapInboundClaims = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = configuration["Auth:OIDC:ValidIssuers"].Split(',').ToList();
                })
                .AddBentleyImsWsFederationAuthentication(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
                {
                    configuration.GetSection("Auth").GetSection("WsFed").Bind(o);
                    List<string> audienceUriList = configuration["Auth:WsFed:TokenValidationParameters:ValidAudiencesURIs"].Split(',').ToList();
                    o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = audienceUriList;
                    o.PassiveRedirect = false;
                    o.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
                    o.BootStrapTokenClaimName = _tokenName;
                });
```

Any ideas as to what could cause this to fail with a stack overflow error intermittently?